# Can I retrieve Custom Metadata Records dynamically in a Lightning Web Component without Apex and without hardcoding ID

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql, custom-metadata

I am trying to build a Lightning Web Component that uses Custom Metadata Types. It will be used on record page. I am successfully retrieving the ID of the current record, then I am using its type as a filter in the Apex class. The cmt records have a "Object type" field and I can easily add a where clause in a SOQL query in the class in order to retrieve only the cmt records which are relevant to the current object. I am wondering is there a way to retrieve these records directly in the LWC without using Apex? The only solutions, I managed to find, are using hardcoded IDs for that purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the best you can do for now. Either a hard coded ID or using Apex.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just one metadata type, you can use the [getAll()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm) method to get all of the records of that type without using a query.  You could pass them from Apex to your LWC and then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) by the object type field.